# Replacing emptry strings with a value adds this value at the start of every string

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a df through reading in an Excel file (`pl.read_excel()`). For some reasons empty cells are `""` instead of `None`/`null`. Replacing those empty strings with another value does not work as expected.

MVE:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"test": ["A", "B", "", "C"]})
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("test").str.replace("", "n.a.", literal=True))
df.head()
```

returns

```
shape: (4, 1)
test
str
"n.a.A"
"n.a.B"
"n.a."
"n.a.C"
```

instead of the expected result

```
shape: (4, 1)
test
str
"A"
"B"
"n.a."
"C"
```

What is the official recommended, idiomatic way to replace empty strings in polars?

Comment: Not really because there is no source that this is the idiomatic way to do so but a rather cumbersome one. Also a lot may have changed in 17 months, especially with library as young as polars, hence my question.

Comment: Yes, and the provided answer should help to get your expected output.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug in `.str.replace` - it appears to be matching the start of the string e.g. as if you did `.str.replace("^", "n.a.")` -

Comment: @jqurious I think so as well. Opened a bug report at github for this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a better way to do this,
modified @jqurious comment by considering the regex patter for empty string i.e., `(^$)`

**Code:**

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"test": ["A", "B", "", "C"]})
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("test").str.replace(r"^$", "n.a."))
df.head()
```

---

**Output:**

```
test
str
"A"
"B"
"n.a."
"C"
```

To handle empty strings with spaces, change the pattern to `"^\s*$"`